# create method event in javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

In the wapp.js I have the following class in JavaScript:

```
function Wapp() {
    this.page = function($page_name) {
        this.onLoad = function($response) {

        }
    }
    this.navigate = {
        changePage: function(link) {
            // Ajax request to load the page
            $.post(link, {}, function(response) {
                // Code to display the page
            });
        }
    }
}
```

in the app.js script I have the following code:

```
var wapp = new Wapp();
```

and I want to do this:

```
wapp.page('home').onLoad(function() {
    // doSomething();
}

// When I call the method 'changePage'
wapp.navigate.changePage('home');

// at the end of the page load 'home' I want to call the function 'doSomething()' inside the 'onLoad' method
```

how should I define the methods within the class to make sure that at the end of a certain action (in this case at the end of the ajax call) to run the code defined within the 'onLoad' method in app.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to assign a function as variable to your class when constructing it. You'll be able to call assigned function later in your code (e.g. in end of the other function)

https://jsfiddle.net/L8c2s6xr/

```
function func (functionToCall) {
  this.functionToCall = functionToCall;

  this.doSomething = function () {
    this.functionToCall();
  }
}

var f = new func (
  function() {
    alert('this works');
  }
);

f.doSomething();
```